# Integrating an ethernet switch IC to custom pcb with mcu using RMII

Tags: ethernet, lpc1768, rmii

I have a custom board with `LPC1768`. It has also PHY (`LAN8720`) in order to connect to LAN via RJ45. So far so good.

Now, I have to extend that custom PCB including Ethernet-switch-IC by a choice of mine. It must have 5 ports minimum and 10/100 only, not gigabit.

Furthermore, I like to connect `LPC1768` directly with that Ethernet-switch on the same board rather than using external PHY (LAN8720). As it seems, `RMII interface` is for that business and LPC1768 supports that. But, I am not sure how to do that and if this is even possible straight forward.

I picked [KSZ8795](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/KSZ8795). It says there is Port5 can be configured as RMII interface.

**My questions;**

1. Can I directly connect LPC1768 to KSZ8795 using it's RMII interface (TXD0, TXD1, TXEN, RXD0, RXD1, CRS, RXER, MDIO, MDC, RESET, RMII_CLK)?
2. if I can connect the way I assumed, apparently a configuration is required to set RMII interface on KSZ8795. If there is, I must missed that in the datasheet. How can I configure KSZ8795?

I appreciate your inputs from now.

Comment: You can configure port 5 for RMII mode by pin strapping or writing to register 0x56 over SPI - see pages 57 and 58 of the datasheet.

Comment: Yes, I can see that register you pointed, thank you. I would prefer to set the register by pin strapping. Do you also confirm the answer for my first question sort of a YES? Can I connect my MCU to that switch with RMII interface on it?

Comment: @Sener For strapping, the switch uses LED3[1:0] (RMII > '01') to set Port 5 MAC mode, see datasheet page 7. I don't see any problem with connecting the MCU to that switch.

Comment: @Cisco I noticed that pins controlling bits 0 and 1 of the 0x56 register as Peter answered. Thank you for confirming MCU can connect to that switch via RMII directly.

Comment: For the records, [this](https://static5.arrow.com/pdfs/2016/2/2/7/28/23/436/mcp_/manual/ksz8795_sck_evl_brd_v1_1schematics.zip) EVAL board schematic reveals many things including RMII via jumpers.